# Access a variable referred back twice UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix, while-loop

This is a simple question, but I have the variables

```
classNext1="Exists!"
classNext2="Exists!"
classNext3="Does not exist yet!"
classNext4="Does not exist yet!"
```

I am trying to figure out which variable is next in order, the next variable that wouldn't equal `"Exists!"`

I have this while loop

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do
    i=`expr $i + 1` # Increment i
    temp="extraClass$i"
    if [ "$($temp)" != 'Exists!' ];then
    echo "SUCUDESSS"
        nextClass="extraClass$i"
        break
    fi
    echo $temp
done
```

The next class in the list would be `classNext3`, but it would just go and assign `nextClass=nextClass1`.

So the if statement would always be true in the first iteration. The problem is that `$temp equals extraClass$i`, it wouldn't actually equal the value of `$extraClass($i)` at the i th iteration. How would I structure it so that the if statement would actually get the value of `$extraClass($i)` instead of the literal string`"extraClass($i)"`??

Comment: You will find your task much easier if you use an array

Comment: There are arrays in unix..? I'm kind of new

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the value of a variable as the name of a variable to access, use variable indirection, as explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
if [ "${!temp}" != 'Exists!' ]; then
```

But whenever you find yourself naming variables with numerical suffixes, and wanting to access them dynamically, that practically always means you should be using an array instead of separate variables. This goes for just about any programming language.